Estimate load capacitance of cascaded inverters
I'm unsure about two points at K.Hoffmann's book: System Integration:
In the section 'Estimation of load capacitances' there is a figure, that shows the parasitic capacitances of a CMOS inverter in resistance region:


Why does \$I_{DS}\$ denote both the gate-drain current and also drain-source current?

Next, the total gate current is given as:
\$I_G(t) = I_S(t) + I_{DS}(t) = 3/2\cdot C_{0x}\cdot \frac{V_{CC}}{\Delta t}\$
and the following figure of resulting capacitances is shown:


Why is there another capacitance from drain to ground and how can the value of \$C_{0x}\$ be derived?


For question 1…
In the figure of a CMOS inverter,  IDS(t)  represents the current flowing between the drain and source of the transistor. Since it’s an NMOS transistor, this current refers to the drain-source current in saturation or triode regions. When the transistor is operating, the drain-source current  IDS(t)  directly impacts the behavior of the gate-drain capacitance  Cgd, influencing the charge and discharge processes through the gate capacitance network. Thus,  IDS(t)  reflects both the current between the drain and source and the current interacting with the gate-drain capacitance, explaining the dual representation , I assume …
For question 2, The capacitance from the drain to ground comes from the layout of the CMOS device and the load. In reality, there’s always some parasitic capacitance due to wiring, packaging, and other nearby devices. This capacitance affects how the circuit behaves, especially at higher frequencies.
The value of  Cox  represents the capacitance related to the oxide in the MOS transistor. This capacitance can be derived from the MOSFET’s physical properties, and it’s generally proportional to the transistor’s gate area, oxide thickness, and permittivity.
Cox=(Eox*Area)/tox


Your total gate current equation is dimensionally wrong.

I can't make sense of the single-FET diagram, and I don't understand why the same IDS(t) is in two different places.


Maybe this will make sense upon close examination of the text in the book but I would advise looking elsewhere for understanding. I don't know the book but from the title my guess is that it's pretty far from device physics.

Sorry, I corrected the equation, it should be dimensionally correct now.
